# ELK APM Framework - APM Server identity could not be verified

Tags: spring-boot, elk, apm, elastic-apm

I am trying to integrate my application with the APM Framework. I've already done it for a series of other applications and everything worked accordingly. This specific Java SpringBoot application gives me the following error:

[image]

I've checked that the TLS certificate is valid in the container that the application is running. As I understand TLS 1.2 is used everywhere. I have checked and updated some http dependencies (okhttp) in case there was an issue with TLS there. No luck. I've checked that the APM SECRET TOKEN I am using is the correct one - and validated the APM environmental variables I've enetered.

I am calling `ElasticApmAttacher.attach();` on the main of my Application class.
I have a elasticapm.properties file as follows:

```
enable_log_correlation=true
service_name=my-api-name
```

The following env vars:

```
ELASTIC_APM_APPLICATION_PACKAGES=my_classpath_here
ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=apm_addresss_here
ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN=token_here
```

Any ideas for what more to look for will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following env var:

`ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=“-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2”`

Dockerfile base image change:

from `java:8-jdk-alpine` to `openjdk:8u272-jdk`

And it worked.